# How to override function/value in a class thats has been extended

Tags: javascript

A little confused on how to over ride a return value in a function.

Example.

```
class Customer {
   getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
}
```

and I have another class that extends the above class. What I am aiming to do is if `getFirstName` is called from Customer, then itll return a value. If however `getFirstName` is called from Client, I want it to return `null`.

```
class Client extends Customer {
    //TODO
}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: You can have `getFirstName(){ return null }` in `class Client`. That's the idea behind inheritance, when children don't have own properties/methods they *inherit* them from the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just override and return null in client class**

```
class Client extends Customer {
         getFirstName() {
            return null
         }
    }
```